# What is a Lifelong Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a **Lifelong Word™**.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Lifelong Words™ | Not Lifelong Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| girl | boy |
| eastern | northern |
| right | left |
| biological | dead |
| master | slave |
| stupid | clever |
| friendship | rivalry |
| bike | automobile |
| lunch | supper |
| amazing | everyday |
| public | private |
| situp | pushup |

**Important**: There are some words which cannot be evaluated with this rule. Examples of undefined words:

> Japanese, Journalism, Jaw, Injection, Prejudice, Joy, Jaywalk, trajectory

CSV version:

```
Lifelong Words™,    Not Lifelong Words™

girl,               boy
eastern,            northern
right,              left
biological,         dead
master,             slave
stupid,             clever
friendship,         rivalry
bike,               automobile
lunch,              supper
amazing,            everyday
public,             private
situp,              pushup
```

---

**What is the special rule these words conform to?**

---

Hint #1:

> Ironically, "John" can also not be evaluated. But he's nonetheless back on the grid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an impressively complicated one, but I'll do my best to explain it! A Lifelong Word is one where:

> If we arrange the letters of the alphabet (except J) into a 5x5 grid and highlight the cells corresponding to the letters which spell the word *and then we run the rules of **[Conway's Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life)** on it within an infinite grid*, the resulting simulation either (i) ends in a static state with some surviving cells, (ii) enters an infinite loop, or (iii) sets off a constantly moving but neverending sequence. By contrast, for words which are Not Lifelong their cells all die out within a few generations.

This explains a few peculiarities in the puzzle:

> 1. The name **Lifelong** contains a reference to **Life** and an implication that it is *long-lasting*.
>
>  2. All words in the 'undefined' list contain the letter J - this is the one letter of the alphabet which must be omitted when running the simulation.
>
>  3. The mention of 'John' in the hint is a reference to the mathematician **[John Horton Conway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Horton_Conway)** who developed this game. The mention of 'grid' also points towards this game specifically.

The simplest result to show is that for GIRL (I used [this tool](https://bitstorm.org/gameoflife/) to check my working), which produces the following:

> [image]
>  After one generation, the L, M and N cells are alive, while the G, R and I cells die out. However, in generation 2 the G and R cells resurrect while L and N die out, and we enter an infinite loop known as a 'blinker', forever fluctuating between the two states.
>
>  Meanwhile, running the game for EASTERN produces *four* infinitely-fluctuating blinkers after 9 generations:
>  [image]
>
>  RIGHT also produces 4 blinkers (after 11 generations), but BIOLOGICAL produces a static state known as a 'loaf' after 3 generations:
>  [image]
>
>  And MASTER results in a 'bee-hive' after 3 generations:
>  [image]
>
>  As for the others:
>  STUPID = 2 bee-hives
>  FRIENDSHIP = 4 'blocks' (2x2 squares)
>  BIKE = 1 block
>  LUNCH = 1 block
>  AMAZING = 1 bee-hive
>  PUBLIC = 3 blocks + 1 blinker
>  SITUP = 1 'glider' - a shape which continually moves onward in a zigzagging (but ultimately straight) line!

Meanwhile the words which are Not Lifelong all 'die out' like so:

> [image]

Comment: Yes, well done! I chose the infinite option because I wanted to make SITUP behave in the way it does ;)

Comment: It was when I realised what shape SITUP made that the truth dawned on me! I had the right idea a little earlier but it wasn't until I twigged the importance of J that I actually made it work. An impressively involved 'What is a Word' puzzle, thank you! :)